# Aspas fechando indevidamente js

Tags: php, javascript

Com um arquivo **PHP** estou inserindo código **javascript**. Portanto estou utilizando o 'echo'.

```
echo ' grammar: "\name = s:[0-9a-zA-Z]+ { return s.join(""); }\n\" ';
```

O problema é que está dando erro porque dentro do `s.join("")` está fechando com as aspas do grammar.

Não consigo mudar para aspas simples dentro do join pq senão fecharia com o echo. Acredito que tenha que tentar escapar as aspas. Alguém saberia como fazer isso?

Comment: Sugiro que coloque o código tal como o tem no seu arquivo, porque a forma como ficou aqui na pergunta não foi clara.  Parece que tem 2 `echo` mas não há `;` a separa-los. De qualquer forma, escapar é sempre com `\`, por isso escapar `'` seria `\'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema ai é que nesse local onde ta dando erro deveria ser aspas simples pelo fato de que a string passada no JS está aberta como aspas duplas. Pra não gerar conflito com a abertura de aspas do echo do php, use um jogo de concatenação, como essa:

```
echo ' grammar: "\name = s:[0-9a-zA-Z]+ { return s.join('."''".'); }\n\" ';
```